# Codeigniter URL rewriting .htaccess is not working on CentOS

Tags: linux, apache, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I've created a .htaccess file in my document root at `/var/www/html/` to rewrite URL of Codeigniter to remove "index.php" from URL of all pages.

e.g. Change URL from

```
http://myhost/index.php/controller/function
```

to

```
http://myhost/controller/function`
```

Here is the code of my `/var/www/html/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

I've got many suggestions from googling to enable mod-rewrite module, but I can see in my `httpd.conf` its already enabled.

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

This is perfectly working on my local system running on Debian 7 (Apache/2.4.4).

Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to also specify the locations that can use it.  For example, in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf you should see something like:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">

      ...lots of text...

</Directory>
```

Make sure is has:

```
<Directory "/var/www/html">

    AllowOverride All

</Directory>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
# CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core) - 
# CodeIgniter 3.1.11 - ( .htaccess - This code work for me )

Options +FollowSymLinks
Options -Indexes
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that your centos server isn't setup to handle PATH INFO. Try replacing the `index.php/$1` in your rule's target to `index.php?/$1`.

Then you need to modify your CI config to enable query strings: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html

In you `application/config.php` file set `$config['enable_query_strings']` to `TRUE`.