# Woocommerce API: GET https://DNS.SERVER.NAME/wc-api/v3/products/categories 404 (Not Found)

Tags: wordpress, api, woocommerce

I have trouble making wc-api/v3 working on my EC2. I have made it work in my mac locally.

The following is what I have done after installing woocommerce and enabling https with self-signed certificate.

1) Enable Api (Default enabled)
2) Change the permlinks option to "Post Name"
3) Generated API key and secret

This is the same setting I did in my mac. There is a small difference due to the folder structure that I have in my mac.

.htaccess in my mac:

```
BEGIN WordPress


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wordpress/
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wordpress/index.php [L]
END WordPress
```

.htaccess in my ec2 instance:

```
BEGIN WordPress


RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
END WordPress
```

CRUL:

```
curl -k https://FQDN.OF.MY.SERER/wc-api/v3/products/categories -u ck_abigkey:cs_abigsecret
```

Output:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">

404 Not Found
Not Found

The requested URL /wc-api/v3/products/categories was not found on this server.

Apache/2.2.31 (Amazon) Server at FQDN.OF.MY.SERVER Port 443
```

Versions in both MAC and EC2:
Wordpress Version: 4.3.1
Woocommerce plugin version: 2.4.7

Answer (score 0):

URL Rewrite was not working and the reason being apache was not configured to allow URL rewrite.

[Codeigniter URL rewriting .htaccess is not working on CentOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20710569/codeigniter-url-rewriting-htaccess-is-not-working-on-centos)